# multiple owl carousel's, target individual with custom navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm in early stages of learning Jquery.
I've got multiple carousels on a single page with custom navigation, I just can't seem to target them individually. They all move when the button is clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var mainowl = $('.owl-carousel');

mainowl.owlCarousel();
$('.card--carousel-controls__next').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    mainowl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
});
$('.card--carousel-controls__prev').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    mainowl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OWL, the Web Ontology Language, [tag:owl], so I've removed that tag.  It usually helps to add language tags, too, so I've added [tag:javascript].

Comment: Good stuff, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add class name ('div_main' or anything you want) in each carousel div tag like as

```
<div class="row__inner owl-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme div_main">
</div>
```

In Javascript

```
$('.card--carousel-controls__next').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
     $(this).closest(".div_main").children('.owl-nav').children('.owl-next').trigger("click");
});

$('.card--carousel-controls__prev').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".div_main").children('.owl-nav').children(".owl-prev").trigger("click");
});
```

I'm not sure it's good solution or not. It's working for me.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I'll give it a go